# Extra days in visit days calendar

Tags: bug, profile-page, visited-days, calendar

Sometimes when using the calendar in the `x days visited, y consecutive`, extra days pop up after the end of the month.

For example (Puzzling):
[image: Feb 28]
or (PPCG):
[image: Jun 29]
or (in the future, Puzzling again):
[image: Nov 30]

I've noticed that these days are days I haven't visited the site.

It's not that important (and I know SE staff are busy) but can this be fixed? It's a small thing, but it annoys me.

Comment: you got extra days to do your stuff

Comment: Does it happen on other SE sites or is it just there to puzzle you? I don't see it on any of the sites I use. This might be browser dependent. Which one are you on?

Comment: @Joonas happens on codegolf too. I use Chrome.

Comment: Also, if anyone else observes this behaviour, can you please comment?

Comment: Can you please provide details of your browser (version) and operating system? Do you have any plugins/add-ons/user scripts installed? If so what happens if you disable them? Do you see any errors in the browser developer tools?

Comment: I have checked in 5 different browsers and could not reproduce this, all on Windows 10.

Comment: @Oded I use windows 10 and Chrome 61.0.3163.100. The only plugin I use is AdBlock, though it appears when I pause it too. No errors pop up, but I get the warning 'slow network detected, fallback font will be used'.

Comment: I do wonder if that means something else is also not loading - is there anything in the developer tools network tab that is not a 200 level response (I expect websockets with 100 level and possibly a few 300, but anything else)?

Comment: @Oded sorry, I don't know what I'm looking for. What I do see is the cells in error contain `<td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>` or `<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>`

Comment: @boboquack - so that's really strange, as it tells me that the HTML doesn't have the numbers, even though you see them. Perhaps a hard refresh (ctrl + f5) will help, or possibly clearing your browser cache. Could be that a corrupt javascript file got cached.

Comment: @Oded I can't reproduce this on my own computer any more :P Do you know anyone who can close this as [tag:status-norepro]?